# Unexpectedly Returning the Main Function and Sorting Strings Function

Tags: c++, string, sorting

I don't know why but this program acts strangely and returns back everything I've inserted with 2 or 3 times the main function and I don't know what is the problem. Besides that I don't know how to use the sort option with strings. I want to write a function that do the sorts the Name of the Book. and I need to add this function (sort function) to the main function. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is a program, that gets the name of the Book and the author and the translator and ISBN and the subject and do search or report them.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct Library
{
    string Book_Name;
    string Author;
    string Translator;
    string ISBN;
    string Subject;
    struct Library *fl, *bl;
}*start, *cur, *p;

void insert()
{
    p = new struct Library;
    p->fl = NULL;
    p->bl = cur;
    cur->fl = p;
    cur = p;
    cout << "Enter the specified informations for Books" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The Name of the Book " << endl;
    getline(cin, p->Book_Name);
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Author" << endl;
    getline(cin, p->Author);
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "The Name of the Translator " << endl;
    getline(cin, p->Translator);
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "International Standard Book Number (ISBN) " << endl;
    getline(cin, p->ISBN);
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter the Subject of the Book " << endl;
    getline(cin, p->Subject);
    cin.ignore();
}

void report_number_1()
{
    cout << "The list of all Books in Library are as below" << endl;
    for (p = start->fl; p != NULL; p = p->fl)
    {
        cout << "Book Name " << p->Book_Name << endl;
        cout << "Author Name " << p->Author << endl;
        cout << "Translator Name " << p->Translator << endl;
        cout << "ISBN of the Book " << p->ISBN << endl;
        cout << "Book Subject " << p->Subject << endl;
    }
}

void delete_number_1()
{
    struct Library *ap, *bp;
    char is[15];
    int sw = 0;
    cout << "Enter ISBN" << endl;
    gets_s(is);
    for (p = start->fl; p != NULL&&!sw; p = p->fl)
    {
        if (p->ISBN == is)
        {
            sw = 1;
            ap = p->fl;
            bp = p->bl;
            bp->fl = ap;
            ap->bl = bp;
            p->fl = NULL;
            p->bl = NULL;
        }
        cout << "Book Name " << p->Book_Name << endl;
        cout << "Author Name " << p->Author << endl;
        cout << "Translator Name " << p->Translator << endl;
        cout << "ISBN of the Book " << p->ISBN << endl;
        cout << "Book Subject " << p->Subject << endl;
    }
}

void report_number_2()
{
    string title;
    int sw = 0;
    cout << "Enter Book's Title " << endl;
    getline(cin,title);
    for (p = start->fl; p != NULL; p = p->fl)
    {
        if (p->Subject == title)
        {
            sw = 1;
            cout << "Book Name " << p->Book_Name << endl;
            cout << "Author Name " << p->Author << endl;
            cout << "Translator Name " << p->Translator << endl;
            cout << "ISBN of the Book " << p->ISBN << endl;
            cout << "Book Subject " << p->Subject << endl;
        }
        if (!sw)
        {
            cout << "ERROR 404 - NOT FOUND" << endl;
        }
    }
}

void delete_number_2()
{
    struct Library *ap, *bp;
    string name;
    int sw = 0;
    cout << "Enter Author's Name or the Translator's Name so that search begins and delete" << endl;
    getline(cin,name);
    for (p = start->fl; p != NULL; p->fl = p)
    {
        if ((p->Author == name) || (p->Translator == name))
        {
            sw = 1;
            ap = p->fl;
            bp = p->bl;
            bp->fl = ap;
            ap->bl = bp;
            p->fl = NULL;
            p->bl = NULL;
        }
        cout << "Book Name " << p->Book_Name << endl;
        cout << "Author Name " << p->Author << endl;
        cout << "Translator Name " << p->Translator << endl;
        cout << "ISBN of the Book " << p->ISBN << endl;
        cout << "Book Subject " << p->Subject << endl;
        delete(p);
    }
    if (!sw)
    {
        cout << "ERROR 404 - NOT FOUND" << endl;
    }
}

void main()
{
    char ch;
    start = new struct Library;
    start->fl = NULL;
    start->bl = NULL;
    cur = start;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter I/i for Insert " << endl;
        cout << "Enter R/r for Report that is Sorted by Name of the Book " << endl;
        cout << "Enter S/s for Search by ISBN and delete the Specific Book " << endl;
        cout << "Enter U/u for search  " << endl;
        cout << "Enter W/w to delete the Specific Book" << endl;
        cout << "Enter X/x for Terminating the Program " << endl;
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 'I':
        case 'i':
            insert();
            break;
        case'R':
        case'r':
            report_number_1();
        case 'S':
        case 's':
            delete_number_1();
            break;
        case 'U':
        case 'u':
            report_number_2();
            break;
        case 'W':
        case 'w':
            delete_number_2();
            break;
        }
    } while (ch != 'X' && ch != 'x');
}
```

Comment: Please use a debugger first, before asking here!

Comment: You should probably give us some example input and the output you were expecting. This is a homework assignment, right?

Comment: "returns back everything I've inserted with 2/3 times the main function" - this is very ambiguous. It is also ambiguous if you want to sort your books using the standard lib, or if you want to implement sorting yourself. Please consider posting your inputs and outputs. If you need to write your own sorting, consider other resources (questions stating "write my sorting algorithm" will be closed), or try to write the algorithm and ask if you get stuck. Voting to close.

Comment: If this is not a homework assignment: Why are you trying to reimplement a non-generic `std::list`?

Comment: actually guys this is not a homework assignment and I don't know what a debugger is, and this is a program that I just wanted to know, how should I use pointers (I am learning C++ for 3 months now) and I've read a lot of articles about sorting but didn't help, I've just hoped you guys could help a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I assume in line

```
for (p = start->fl; p != NULL; p->fl = p)
```

in delete_number_2() the last part of the for loop should be

```
p = p->fl
```

Comment: oh and btw you are never deleting anything which isn't that good :)

Comment: Thanks, but still not working, if I type more letters I get more of the main function, I don't know why!

Comment: Please be a little more precise. What do you input and what happens with the program (what is the output, is there a crash ..) ?

Comment: Ok I had a quick look at it using the debugger. The problem is caused by your input stream (cin). It gets messed up with the input so after a call to insert() there are still characters in the stream that cause the problem. Remove all the cin.ignore() in the insert() will help. In the switch(ch) statement in your main loop there is a break; missing after report_number_1() wich causes an immediate delete_number_1() call afterwards. Insert will work once you removed the "cin.ignore()"s. Start from there and fix the remaining functions :)

Comment: thank you very much, but there is still a problem, the first line will be ignored (The Name of the Book).

Comment: You can insert a cin.ignore(); after the cin >> ch; in the main loop. As I said there are some more problems but I think you should have a rough idea now where to look at and do the rest on your own.